# textViewDidChange is not call when change UITextView.inputView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I drag a `UITextView` and hook up delegate with `File's Owner`.
The `textViewDidChange` is called only with default keyboard, but nothing happen when input text from my keyboard.

How to enable delegate of `UITextView` when set its `inputView` to a custom keyboard?

Here is my code

ViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    self.myKeyboard = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyKeyboard" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.myKeyboard setTextView:self.textView];
}

#pragma mark TestViewDelegate
    - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
        NSLog(@"TextDidChange: %@",textView.text);
    }
```

MyKeyboard.h

```
@interface MyKeyboard : UIView
@property (weak,nonatomic) id<UITextInput> textView;
-(void)setTextView:(id<UITextInput>)textView;
@end
```

MyKeyboard.m

```
 -(void)setTextView:(id<UITextInput>)textView{
        _textView = textView;
        if ([textView isKindOfClass:[UITextView class]])
            [(UITextView *)textView setInputView:self];
        else if ([textView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            [(UITextField *)textView setInputView:self];
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the delegate set anywhere.  Have you run `textView.delegate = self`?

Answer (score 13):

In your custom keyboard, you probably change text inside `textView` by using method `setText:`, but changes made in this method doesn't call a `textViewDidChanged` callback.
Read more in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#jumpTo_7).

> **textViewDidChange:**
>   Discussion
>
> The text view calls this method in response to user-initiated changes
>   to the text. **This method is not called in response to programmatically
>   initiated changes.**

So, you should manually call this method from your keyboard.