# iOS textViewDidChange is not triggered when predictive text is selected and added to text

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextview

[image]

When I tap on "Hello" or "He", textViewDidChange is not triggered.

How to detect when predictive text is selected?

Comment: From memory I think it's an option set in the storyboard

Comment: @mthud To detect predictive text used?

Comment: I thought so, but it's a vague recollection sorry I'm not at my Mac... worth a look tho

Comment: @Alex any updates about it?

Comment: an answer about it https://stackoverflow.com/a/22613155/4981515

Comment: I'm experiencing this problem too but only when using predictive text to modify a selected word in the middle of my text view. When adding words with predictive text to the end of the text view, the `textViewDidChange` method is being called. (Xcode 11.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

I had to use the NotificationCenter to get notified when a UITextView changes.
I've created an extension of UITextView to register/unregister for those notifications. Just remember to call unregister when you would no longer want to keep handling those changes (E.g. on `viewWillDisappear`).

```swift
import UIKit

extension UITextView {

    public func registerTextViewNotifications() {
        let center = NotificationCenter.default
        center.addObserver(self,
                           selector: #selector(textViewDidChangeWithNotification(_:)),
                           name: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification,
                           object: nil)
    }

    public func unregisterTextViewNotifications() {
        let center = NotificationCenter.default
        center.removeObserver(self,
                              name: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification,
                              object: nil)
    }

    @objc private func textViewDidChangeWithNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
        // Do something when edited
        print("Text: \(String(describing: text))")
    }

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        textView.registerTextViewNotifications()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        textView.unregisterTextViewNotifications()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `shouldChangeTextInRange` instead of `textViewDidChange`
I tried it and it is triggered with predictive text

Comment: shouldChangeTextInRange does reflect when auto complete is used, but Im not able to differentiate cursor position change with auto complete, as both event triggers shouldChangeTextInRange

Answer (score 0):

Do you have set textView.delegate ?

Comment: Yep! textViewDidChange is triggered as I typed but when I use the predictive text, textViewDidChange is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

1. `YourViewController<UITextViewDelegate>`
2. After setup the textView, `textView.delegate = self`
3. `func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView)`:

   `func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
       //textView(Sender)
       if(textView == yourtextview) {
           //do something
      } 
   }`